# Interceptor not getting called in Struts

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

My interceptor (**validation**) is not getting called before or after the action. Any ideas how to get it work ?

Note : Everytime the **default** interceptor is being called.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
      <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
    </result-types>

    <interceptors>
       <interceptor name="validation" class="ValidatorBaseAction"/>
      <interceptor-stack name="default">
        <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>
      </interceptor-stack>
      <interceptor-stack name="validationStack">
         <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
         <interceptor-ref name="default"/>
      </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="default" />

    <action
        name="viewRequest"
        class="ViewAction"
        method="execute">
      <interceptor-ref name="validationStack" /> 
      <result name="input" type="redirectAction">explore</result>
      <result name="success" type="redirect">/showRequest.do?${explorerParameters}</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Which interceptor is not getting called ?

Comment: Did you try with this `<interceptor-stack name="validationStack">

         <interceptor-ref name="default"/>
         <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>

      </interceptor-stack>`

Comment: How did you know it's not called?

Comment: Default stack name is `defaultStack`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Main problem:

- `class` both for Actions and Interceptors must specify the **FQCN**, not only the name. Then change it to something like:

  ```xml
  <interceptor name="validation" class="com.foo.bar.ValidatorBaseAction"/>
  ```

  and also change your action to

  ```xml
  <action name="viewRequest" class="com.foo.bar.ViewAction" method="execute">
  ```

#### Side problems:

- Don't call it `ValidatorBaseAction` if it is an `Interceptor`, call it `ValidatorBaseInterceptor`. And ensure there is ***nothing* of an Action** inside it;
- Don't use an Interceptor Stack **with only one Interceptor**, I'm pretty sure it would be useless in 99% of the cases. If you are not sure, just use the defaultStack, adding your interceptor to it.

#### Polishing:

- [`json-default`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin/2.3.20/struts-plugin.xml) already extends `struts-default`, so this

  ```xml
  <package ... extends="struts-default,json-default"
  ```

  is equivalent to this

  ```xml
  <package ... extends="json-default"
  ```

  that is cleaner;
- Since you extends json-default, you don't need to redefine the JSON result, then remove

  ```xml
  <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" />
  ```

  that is useless.
- Try always to prefer `redirectAction` result when redirecting to an Action, and use `redirect` result only when redirecting to other resources or external URLs

Comment: I have just stripped the FQCN from the snippet I have here. I actually have them in my code. Also I could not add the validation to default stack as I need it only for selective actions.

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense, please explain it better

Comment: I could not add my interceptor to the default stack as default stack is used by a lot more actions and I need my interceptor in only a subset of those actions.

Comment: Absolutely! Just include in your validationStack the validation interceptor AND the defaultStack, instead of your minimal default stack composed by one interceptor only. defaultStack != default....

Comment: The problem is even after I explicitly use my validation interceptor in the action, the default one is called. If I change the default-interceptor-ref only then my interceptor is called.

Comment: This is weird... 1) Do not arbitrary "strip" things when posting a code that does not work (have you strip something else that we should know ?) 2) How do you know that your interceptor is not being called ? 3) How do you know that the "default" stack (YOUR "default", not the real defaultStack) is being called ? 4) Always use unique names. `validation` is the name of another Interceptor. BTW if the problem persists, consider posting your Interceptor, action class, full struts config and web.xml